# Is there a way to whitelist a range of IP addresses for parental control?

Tags: plist, parental-controls

The IP addresses in `/Library/Managed\ Preferences/<user>/com.apple.familcontrols.contentfilter.plist` are each listed separately.  Is there a way to add a range of addresses?

Many companies (including Google) use a range of IP addresses with no associated domain.  Currently, each IP address has to be added separately.  And that's quite painful.